# Using Dispatch group to return value from closure pause the UI

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

My requirement is to return the value from closure so I tried Dispatch group.

```
    func retrieveAccessToken()->String {
       var accessToken: String?
       let group = DispatchGroup()
       if !accessTokenExpired(){
           Network.instance.networkRequest() { value in
               accessToken = value
               group.leave()
          }
       } else {
           accessToken = KeychainHandler.shared[ACCESS_TOKEN]!
        }
        group.wait()
       return accessToken!
    }
```

if I don't use the dispatch group, the function returns nil,
if I use it my UI gets frozen.
I searched many questions but I didn't find any with my requirement.
Please mark duplicate and provide the link if this question is already solved.
Again, **My requirement is to return the value, not to call or print the value inside the closure.**

Comment: you need to pass a closure to your retrieveAccessToken fuction

Comment: You *cannot* wait on the main thread for completion of the request without blocking the main thread.

Comment: @AbhinavJha If this is the only requirement then you need to learn diff b/w `synchronous` and `asynchronous`.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to prevent it from freezing your UI is to wrap it in backgroundQueue but then you wont be able to return a string, What you need is

```
func retrieveAccessToken(block : ((String) -> ())) {
    var accessToken: String! = nil
    if !accessTokenExpired(){
        Network.instance.networkRequest() { value in
            accessToken = value
            block(accessToken)
        }
    } else {
        accessToken = KeychainHandler.shared[ACCESS_TOKEN]!
        block(accessToken)
    }

}
```

Call it as

```
    self.retrieveAccessToken { (accessToken) in
        //do whatever you wanna do here
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I think it makes sense to make accessToken as implicit optional because you expect the string to be returned at the end.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari,  i have already mentioned, "My requirement is to return the value, not to call or print the value inside the closure.". I dont want to use closure to send the value

Comment: @abhinav-jha : And we are saying you cant return from a asynchronous function In your case Network.instance.networkRequest is asynchronous call, u are using dispatch group to make it synchronous that will block your UI but if you wrap it in backgroundQueue, DispatchQueue.background will take closure as argument and you cant return a value from block u need a block

Comment: So there is no way to return a value outside closure?, Thanks for your help, i will follow the closure method then.

Comment: @abhinav-jha : Nope buddy, sorry no other way

Comment: I just used a completionhandler inside notify(queue: .main) to return the value and it doesn't freeze the main app flow. Am I missing a point here?

Answer (score 0):

You need completion for that , Can you try

```
func retrieveAccessToken(completion: @escaping (_ str: String) -> Void){ 

     if !accessTokenExpired(){

        Network.instance.networkRequest() { value in

             completion(value) 
        }
    } else {

           completion(KeychainHandler.shared[ACCESS_TOKEN]!)
    }

}
```

//

Call it like this

```
retrieveAccessToken { (token) in

    // get the token
}
```

Also make sure that the api call is asynchronous

Comment: i have already mentioned, "My requirement is to return the value, not to call or print the value inside the closure.". I dont want to use closure to send the value

Comment: it's asynchronous you have to